# Como sumo los datos de diferentes arreglos que vienen de un forEach en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, javascript-objeto

les explico mi problema:
Tengo un carrito de compras, cuando agrego un producto al carrito se guarda en local storage como un arreglo, entonces si agrego 3 productos diferentes el arreglo quedaría de la siguiente manera para cada producto agregado:

```
0: {imagen: "http://localhost:8888/raivtech-web/tienda/admin/img/products/publicidad-mantenimiento.jpg", titulo: "iPhone 7", precio: "15000", id: "29"}
```

La situación es que requiero obtener el campo de precio para cada producto para poder sumarlos, los obtengo con un forEach pero como vienen de diferentes arreglos no puedo manipularlos.

```js
function procederCompraFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let productosLS;

  productosLS = obtenerProductosLocalStorage();

  productosLS.forEach(function(producto) {
    var precio = parseInt(producto.precio);
    console.log(precio);
  });
}
```

El console.log de precio lanza 3 arreglos solo con el campo de precio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui te dejo otra alternativa usando **"For of"**

```js
function procederCompraFunction() {

    let total = 0;
    let productosLS = obtenerProductosLocalStorage();

    for (let producto of productosLS) {
        total += parseFloat(producto.precio);
    }

    //Este seria el total de todos los productos
    console.log(total);
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido por favor lee ]answer], los aportes que son solo código se consideran de baja calidad, considera editar y agregar una explicación

Answer (score 1):

Aqui te pongo un ejemplo, puedes usar la funcion ***reduce*** de javascript para sumar todos los precios, y tambien usar ***parseFloat*** en ves de ***parseInt***

```js
function obtenerProductosLocalStorage(){
   return [
    {precio : 10.20},
    {precio : 21.75},
    {precio : 12.10},
   ]
}

function procederCompraFunction(e) {
  if(e) e.preventDefault();
  let productosLS;

  productosLS = obtenerProductosLocalStorage();

  let total = productosLS.reduce(function(acumulado, producto) {
    return acumulado + parseFloat(producto.precio);
  }, 0);
  console.log(total)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="procederCompraFunction()">
  Comprar
</button>
```